# How can I read what is in a database and checking if a certain string is in there? i am using python with sqlite3

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Instead of reading and fetching data from my database, how would i go about reading the database and just checking that a certain piece of data is in there?

I have created a database for a login system holding emails, passwords etc and would like the user to say whether or not they already have a login.

At the moment users can create a login, but if they say they already have one, i would like to read through the database and check that the email they have typed in is in there and if their password matches up with the one stored with their email.

Comment: you have to learn SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLite` databases are just files, but your simplest method of retrieval is just going to be to query your database.

You would simply query for the email and password combination and verify against what the user has entered.  Imagine you have a simple schema that is `name, email, password`, just run a SQL command like `SELECT email, password FROM table WHERE name == (name of user)`.  If you're using a Python client, you will do that with a `cursor` object, and then just call the `cursor.fetchall()` method to return tuples of results.

In your case there should be 1 or 0 results, so it should be easy to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to use the **LIKE** SQL statement in your query i guess. For instance ... "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_field Like '%my_string%' " !